# How can I find DataSource detail of SSAS cube?

Tags: odbc, ssas

I have an SSAS database (Cube) that uses a DataSource with "DsTest" name, when I see the connection string properties I cannot find the server IP anywhere, Plz look at this picture :

[image: picture]

what is this "Data Source = DsTest0" ??Where has it been defined ? There is nothing in "ODBC" list , nor in ".../etc/hosts"

I know the datasource is an Oracle database in a different server but I cannot find where the server IP is defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It had defined in **TNSNAMES.ora** file in this directory :

C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_64\Network\admin\tnsnames.ora

you can find more information here : [TNSNAMES Setup](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/install121010-1979179.html)